# how to execute NPM commands from a PowerShell script

Tags: node.js, powershell, npm

I want to run the command "npm init" in a powershell script. the command is executed, but it stops after displaying info, it never gets to the configure part (see picture). 
after this powershell stops and I have to end the process.

[image: result after running script]

Script.ps1:

```
Write-Host "Initiating a LC Core Project";
npm init;
```

Comment: npm init is probably waiting for user input. Use `npm init -y` to accept all defaults

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen but I want to answer the questions

Comment: If you have found an answer to this, please post it. I guess you've found the answer by now, and it could save a lot of people time, including me.